# Windows stops copying files after a few folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, file-sharing

I'm trying to copy a folder of mine to my other machine. The other machine got a folder shared. I have read/write access, and can copy files. Sometimes. Sometimes not. For some reason it just stops sometimes.

How can I check what's the cause? (It only says "check network connectivity" and permissions.)

It's connected via a LAN cable (both PCs). There is no sign of any connection drop on both sides. (Packet loss is also 0%.) And if Windows stops, it won't let me copy the files NO MATTER WHAT. I'm stuck there

Answer (score 1):

Try Microsoft's robocopy (it comes with Windows). It will automatically retry when a file or folder can't be moved.

- robocopy Z:\src\ C:\dst\ /S /R:30

Will recursively copy from Z:\src\ to C:\dst, retrying any file or folder that fails 30 times.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the network connection is probably dropping and windows stops the transfer. The best thing to do is to use a File/Copy Manager, which handles such situations and remembers what is left to copy after reconnect.

A good manager would be [Teracopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy).

Comment: I managed to copy the files with Total Commander, but the connection is rock solid.

Comment: @Shiki where d do you know from that the connection is rock solid?

Comment: It's connected via a LAN cable (both PCs). There is no sign of any connection drop on both sides. (Packet loss is also 0%.) And if Windows stops, it won't let me copy the files NO MATTER WHAT. I'm stuck there.